# How to use superscript?

Tags: android

I have an app in which I want to set Superscript in a Text view. To do this I am using Html.fromHtml() which are not working below 4.1.2 versions.Let me know Ho do I do that.

```
String result = type+ 2 + "<sup><small>" + power1 + "</small></sup>";
iconText.setText(Html.fromHtml(result));
```

Comment: iconText.setText(Html.fromHtml("X<sup>2</sup>"));

Comment: I am doing the same as you can see my code

Comment: what is type here? plz paste the full code

Comment: type="+".......

Comment: print , result & paste here

Comment: +2<sup><small>3</small></sup>

Comment: +2^3 .... this is the result & no problem to view in textview in my emulator

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SpannableStringBuilder` to make `Superscript` like below :

```
SpannableStringBuilder cs = new SpannableStringBuilder("+23");
cs.setSpan(new SuperscriptSpan(), 2, 3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
iconText.setText(cs);
```

Comment: while setting textview.setText(cs) it is stating error.

Comment: replace textview with iconText

Comment: iconText is actually a Textview

Comment: i want +2 with power 3